# How can I change a div to another with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slide

I have a checkbox that should change which part of the form is showed. Actually, it's just appear/disappear by using `display: none;`. I tried to add animation like that:

```js
function change(event) {
  document.getElementById('part1').style.display = (event.target.checked ? null : 'none');
  document.getElementById('part2').style.display = (event.target.checked ? 'none' : null);
}
```

```css
.animated {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="my-check">Click here</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-check" onchange="change(event)">
</div>
<div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="animated" id="part1">
    <input type="text" name="thing1"><label for="thing1">Thing 1</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="thing2"><label for="thing2">Thing 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="animated" id="part2">
    <select>
      <option>Else</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<input type="text" name="other"><label for="other">Other</label>
```

But there is no valid animation. How can I make it to slide up new, and slide down old ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation should be coupled with height edition. In this example, the first loop is to set default values, exactly like if the user already changed it. I set `height: 0px;` by default to the one that is hidden by default.

```js
for(const wrapper of document.querySelectorAll(".collapse-wrapper")) {
    if(wrapper.style.height != '0px') { // set real height
        const height = wrapper.querySelector(".collapse-content").getBoundingClientRect().height
        wrapper.style.height = `${height}px`;
    }
}

function change() {
    for(const wrapper of document.querySelectorAll(".collapse-wrapper")) {
        if(wrapper.style.height == '0px') {
            const height = wrapper.querySelector(".collapse-content").getBoundingClientRect().height
            wrapper.style.height = `${height}px`;
        } else {
            wrapper.style.height = '0px'
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.collapse-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 300ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <label for="my-check">Click here</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-check" onchange="change()">
</div>
<div class="collapse-wrapper" style="height: 0px;">
  <div class="collapse-content">
    <input type="text" name="thing1"><label for="thing1">Thing 1</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="thing2"><label for="thing2">Thing 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse-wrapper">
  <div class="collapse-content">
    <select>
      <option>Else</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<input type="text" name="other"><label for="other">Other</label>
```